# How to disable the parent form when a child form is active?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to disable a parent form when child form is active using c#?

Comment: Can't you just use ChildForm.show then Mainform.disable / .hide or are you talking about having 2 forms active at same time and when child form is ( active to disable the main ) then on (unfocus) re-activate the mainforM?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle: hey man, i'm looking for exactly your described solution "having 2 forms active at same time and when child form is ( active to disable the main ) then on (unfocus) re-activate the mainforM"
can you give me a hint how to solve that? i've tried it with threading, application.run, etc. but nothing works. how would you realize this?

Answer (score 197):

Have you tried using [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(VS.71).aspx) instead of [Form.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx)?

ShowDialog shows your window as modal, which means you cannot interact with the parent form until it closes.

Comment: doesn't this hide the parent form?

Comment: @barlop to hide the parent form use `this.Hide()` in the parent form code.

Comment: @vee  You misread me. I was asking why was it seeming to hide it(when I didn't wanted it to).  My issue, resolved, was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171607/c-sharp-winforms-how-can-i-get-the-child-form-in-front-of-parent-form-without

Comment: Thanks @R. Martinho Fernandes, this works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 40):

Are you calling `ShowDialog()` or just `Show()` on your child form from the parent form?

`ShowDialog` will "block" the user from interacting with the form which is passed as a parameter to `ShowDialog`.

Within the parent you might call something like:

```
MyChildForm childForm = new MyChildForm();

childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

where `this` is the parent form.

Comment: Works for me! VB.Net version is this: `Public childForm As New Childformclass` and `childForm.ShowDialog(Me)` where Me is the class parent (parent form) thank you so much @Philip

Answer (score 19):

Its simple, use

```
Form.ShowDialog();
```

Instead of

```
Form.Show();
```

While using `Form.ShowDialog()`, you cannot interact with the parent form until it closes.

Comment: when I try it I find that that hides it

Answer (score 11):

What you *could* do, is to make sure to pass the parent form as the owner when showing the child form:

```
  Form newForm = new ChildForm();
  newForm.Show(this);
```

Then, in the child form, set up event handlers for the `Activated` and `Deactivate` events:

```
private void Form_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Owner != null)
    {
        this.Owner.Enabled = false; 
    }
}

private void Form_Deactivate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Owner != null)
    {
        this.Owner.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

However, this will result in a truly wierd behaviour; while you will not be able to go back and interact with the parent form immediately, activating any other application will enable it, and then the user can interact with it.

If you want to make the child form [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), use `ShowDialog` instead:

```
  Form newForm = new ChildForm();
  newForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: You can also handle Form_Closed instead of Form_Deactivate, if you want to disable the parent form for the lifetime of the child form, regardless of other forms or applications being activated in the mean time.

Answer (score 8):

While using the previously mentioned childForm.ShowDialog(this) will disable your main form, it still doesent look very disabled. However if you call Enabled = false before ShowDialog() and Enable = true after  you call ShowDialog() the main form will even look like it is disabled.

```
var childForm = new Form();
Enabled = false;
childForm .ShowDialog(this);
Enabled = true;
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work.. when I try it it hides the parent form

Answer (score 6):

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.Owner = this;
child.Show();
```

// In ChildForm_Load:

```
private void ChildForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  this.Owner.Enabled = false;
}

private void ChildForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  this.Owner.Enabled = true;
}
```

source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae8ef4ef-3ac9-43d2-b883-20abd34f0e55/how-can-i-open-a-child-window-and-block-the-parent-window-only

Answer (score 4):

```
Form1 frmnew = new Form1();
frmnew.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 4):

@Melodia

Sorry for this is not C# code but this is what you would want, besides translating this should be easy.

**FORM1**

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseEnter
    Me.Focus()
    Me.Enabled = True
    Form2.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseLeave
    Form2.Enabled = True
    Form2.Focus()
End Sub
```

**FORM2**

```
Private Sub Form2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseEnter
    Me.Focus()
    Me.Enabled = True
    Form1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseLeave
    Form1.Enabled = True
    Form1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks alot! your idea is great! i just found out that it also works by working with form-parents and docking children to them.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the following:

```
Form3 formshow = new Form3();

formshow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use MDIParent-child form. Set the child form's parent as MDI Parent

Eg

```
child.MdiParent = parentForm;
child.Show();
```

In this case just 1 form will be shown and the child forms will come inside the parent.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For me this work for example here what happen is the main menu will be disabled when you open the registration form.

```
 frmUserRegistration frmMainMenu = new frmUserRegistration();
    frmMainMenu.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to simulate a Form.ShowDialog call but WITHOUT blocking anything (kinda like a Simulated Dialog Form) you can try using Form.Show() and as soon as you show the simulated dialog form then immediately disable all other windows using something like...

```
private void DisableAllWindows()
{
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
if (f.Name != this.Name)f.Enabled = false;
else f.Focus();
}
```

Then when you close your "pseudo-dialog form" be sure to call....

```
private void EnableAllWindows()
{
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) f.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st way

```
MyChildForm childForm = new MyChildForm();
childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

2nd set the parent form enable to False

```
Parent.Enabled = false;
```

Make sure to set it to true when child form close

Answer (score -2):

Why not just have the parent wait for the child to close. This is more than you need.

```
// Execute child process
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: -1: Don't you ever dare to do that in click/press/mouse/key handlers. Info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470256/process-waitforexit-asynchronously

Comment: This answer is about PROCESSES, not about FORMS. Useful to someone, but does not address the question. Its also a really bad idea, if done on the GUI thread -- your app GUI will be locked up until the other process returns -- if anything goes wrong, user will have to resort to task manager to kill your app. USE WITH CAUTION!  Or even better: use some ASYNCHRONOUS solution, rather than WaitForExit.