# parent form is accessible when child form is open

Tags: c#

I have created a parent form and a child form in c# when i click a menu item in parent form, it opens the child form but still i access the parent form.i want that the parent form will remain inaccesible until the child form is open.please send me the code.thnks

Comment: What reason should we specify for closing for question containing "send me the code"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable parent form when child form is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130208/disable-parent-form-when-child-form-is-active)

Comment: @khachik, I think that falls under "not a real question", but such questions are usually duplicates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably** you should use `form.ShowDialog()` method instead of `form.Show()`

**Definitely** you should add a better description, at least framework you are using (WinForms?). C# is not a framework.

Answer (score 3):

try with this

```
form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog. this error msg is displayed when i use ShowDailog() method

Comment: In this case you can use kalyan answer. That means when you are finished doing in the child form the parent form can be made visible again

Comment: Do you need the MDI child form or is a normal form sufficient? (Hence the error you get). How are you using the childform?

Answer (score 1):

Use, `form.Hide()` process to make the Parent form to be not accessable when ever the child form opens and again give `form.show()` to activate the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your parent form visible while showing your child form then you can do following.

```
form.ShowDialog(this).
```

Where `this` is the instance of your parent form.

On the other hand, if you want your parent form hide while showing child form you can do following

```
this.Hide();
form.ShowDialog(this)
```