# How can I disable the parent window in C# when the child window is open?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, showdialog

I have a timer class that I created that monitors the license of the software.  When an error occurs I call ShowDialog() to show my customized windows form.  My problem is how can I disable the parent window?  Here's a simple example of my problem.  As you can see once the MessageBox pops up, you can still type from the MainForm window.

MainForm1.cs file

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  

namespace TestProject  
{  
    public partial class MainForm1 : Form  
    {  
        public MainForm1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
        }  

        private void MainForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            TimerClass1 timer = new TimerClass1();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

MessageBox.cs file

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  

namespace TestProject  
{  
    public partial class MessageBox : Form  
    {  
        public MessageBox()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            this.label1.Text = "Hello There";  
            this.button1.Text = "OK";  
            this.button1.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

TimerClass1.cs file

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Timers;  
using System.Windows;  

namespace TestProject  
{  
    class TimerClass1  
    {  
        Timer _timer;  
        public TimerClass1()  
        {  
            _timer = new Timer(1);  
            _timer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);  
            _timer.Enabled = true;  
        }  

        private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            _timer.Stop();  
            MessageBox msg = new MessageBox();  
            msg.ShowDialog();  
            _timer.Start();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130208/disable-parent-form-when-child-form-is-active

Comment: Just from reading this code I would say the main window should be non-responsive. But making your own MessageBox class is confusing things.

Comment: Also, why is timer calling messagebox? If you want showdialog to work, it should be called from the mainform.

Answer (score 2):

You're showing the `MessageBox` on a separate thread, so it doesn't show as a modal dialog of the main window. You need to show it on the main UI thread:

```
    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        _timer.Stop();  
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
        () => {
            MessageBox msg = new MessageBox();  
            msg.ShowDialog();  
        }));
        _timer.Start();  
    }
```

Comment: Or just use a more sensible Timer class.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, just change the following:

TimerClass1.cs file

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
//using System.Timers;  
using System.Windows;
```

and then fix the errors that result from switching to Windows.Forms.Timer (the one you need).

Comment: This is a WPF app, not a WinForms app; he should use a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`

Comment: OK, answer stays mostly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to access the MainForm1 from TimerClass1.  Once you've done that, you can create and call a method on MainForm1 that will disable the form itself or the controls on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the **parent form** as a parameter to your timer, and showing dialog as follow should make the trick:

**MainForm1.cs** file

```
TimerClass1 timer = new TimerClass1(this);
```

**TimerClass1.cs** file

```
..
private Form ParentForm {get; set;}
..
public TimerClass1(Form parentForm)           
{
..
this.ParentForm = parentForm;
..   
}
..
private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)           
{
..
 msg.ShowDialog(this.ParentForm);
..
} 
..
```