# WPF application stuck when process is WaitForExit()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF application with a button, when the button clicked it calls to a method that start a process - cmd command, the cmd command can take 1 minute. The problem is, at this time (when the process wait for exit and get a result) the application is stuck.

My code in the UI is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // the method Import take 1 minute
    var result = Helpers.Import();
    if (result)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Sucess", "Sucess");
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error",);
    }
}
```

My code in the BL is:

```
public static bool Import()
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\witadmin.exe", arguments);
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process p = Process.Start(info);
    p.WaitForExit();

    if (p.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the application waits for the exit code the UI is stuck.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [process.WaitForExit() asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470256/process-waitforexit-asynchronously)

Comment: Don't call `WaitForExit` in UI thread. You can create a new task and `await` for it. Consider adding more code (ideally [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so that someone can quickly make it asynchronous.

Comment: @FakeCaleb I tried the answers there but without success, I added more code to my question.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk the answers on the post should work, I recommend updating your question with your attempted implementation of those answers to see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in like @Sinatr's comment, I made the method `Button_Click` async, and open a new Task.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   bool result = false;
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
       import = Helpers.Import();
   });
   if (result)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Sucess", "Sucess");
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error",);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

method `WaitForExit()` -> instructs the Process component to wait an infinite amount of time for the process and event handlers to exit. This can cause an application to stop responding.

Comment: I know that WaitForExit() it the reason, but I need to use it because I want the ExitCode, I need a way to use it and still not to be stuck.

Comment: Okey after you get value from ExitCode, are you closing process?

Comment: call Close() when the associated process has terminated. Close free memory allocated to the exited process.