# C# Intentional Loop. (Low CPU Usage)

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

---

## **EDIT:** **Thanks everyone for providing their answers here is the project completed.**

---

## https://github.com/0xyg3n/ProcessDaemon/

---

## *If someone comes up with multi thread solution that might work better i think.*

---

I am new in C# and i would like to ask what is the best way to create an intentional infinite loop that does not destroy your cpu usage... More like as a daemon.

Concept of Software is : 
Create a software that is able to determine if a specific process is running in order to execute a block of code break the loop and make the loop again. I know how to scan the processes and make the loop etc etc but i want something lightweight. C# by default is running as single thread , maybe if i did the while(true) as multi threaded that would solve my problem???

Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessDaemon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            void CP()
            {
                Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                if (pname.Length == 0)
                {
                    //if not running
                }
                else
                {
                    //if running
                    //break the code
                    //retry loop
                }
            }


            void cronCP()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    CP();
                }
            }

            cronCP(); //scan the processes infinitely.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All you need is a `Timer`.

Comment: Well a timer could do what i need but i don't want a timer for that because i want for it to be instant responsive.

Comment: The solution you accepted isn't instantly responsive either.  It will also do its work every 1 sec.

Comment: Yes but the cpu usage is really not that bad ! i do believe though that the best way would be with multi threads.  i just don't know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your code into async code and then add a Task.Delay(xx) to release the process while awaiting

```
namespace ProcessDaemon
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            void CP()
            {
                Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                if (pname.Length == 0)
                {
                    //if not running
                }
                else
                {
                    //if running
                    //break the code
                    //retry loop
                }
            }


            async Task cronCP()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    CP();
                }
            }

            await cronCP(); //scan the processes infinitely.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this make the process lightweight and is this a proper way to make a loop as a deamon?? Like in the near future i might use that for different things, like as an event listener! Wait for something to happen and then trigger a specific action. But yes the question is if it is the right way to do it like that?

Comment: Async is good and I thought that the Process itself might be an awaitable handle or similar, but then I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/470288/2048821 - seems as though the Process class can raise events, so it was made with this in mind - just get the process once and then respond to it's event. Just need a way to stop the main thread from closing now. You could maybe do that with a ManualResetEventSlim.