# Robust way to start a process, read all output and wait for a timeout

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, process

.NET Core has the `Process` class that can start a process. You can also read its stdout and stderr streams and write something to stdin. And you can wait for the process to exit in a specified time. The problem is, it takes massive amounts of code and still doesn't work correctly in all situations.

Reading synchronously won't miss a line of output and tell you exactly when you have all output. But it may block if the called program generates too much output (> 4 kB?).

Reading asynchronously should resolve the "buffer full" blocking, but can't tell you when you have all the output. And it might miss some output at the start.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139593/143684) and all the comments of its highest voted answer summarise the diverse issues quite well.

So I'm looking for an implementation that can:

- Start a process with arguments
- Lets me send data to its input
- Gets me the full contents of its output (stdout and stderr)
- Waits for a specified time and kills the process if it didn't return timely
- Lets me move on when I have the final result (timeout/exit code and all output so far)

The 2020 edition for .NET Core 3.1 on Windows and Linux.

It would also be nice to wait for the process asynchronously. I have [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461641) [code](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AwaitExtensions.cs) for that, and again, it's huge for what it does.

If somebody from Microsoft could add the solution to their sparse documentation, it would be much appreciated. I couldn't find the relevant GitHub repo anymore to report that insufficient documentation.

Here's what I have now, and it doesn't work for larger output: (process won't exit and needs to be killed)

```cs
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "dotnet",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
psi.ArgumentList.Add("--list-runtimes");   // A few pages output on my PC
string standardOutput;
string standardError;
using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
    bool timedOut = false;
    // Sync version
    if (!process.WaitForExit(10000))
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to clean things up
            process.Kill();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Might have exited after all during the short period of time before
            // calling Kill(). And if it fails for other reasons, we can't help it here.
        }
        timedOut = true;
    }
    // BEGIN Async alternative
    using var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    using var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, timeoutCts.Token);
    try
    {
        await process.WaitForExitAsync(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == cts.Token)
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to clean things up
            process.Kill();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Might have exited after all during the short period of time before
            // calling Kill(). And if it fails for other reasons, we can't help it here.
        }
        timedOut = true;
    }
    // END Async alternative

    standardOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    standardError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    if (timedOut)
    {
        logger?.LogError($"The command did not complete in time.\n" +
            $"Output: {standardOutput.TrimEnd()}\nError: {standardError.TrimEnd()}");
        standardOutput = null;
    }
    else if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    {
        logger?.LogError($"The command failed with exit code {process.ExitCode}.\n" +
            $"Output: {standardOutput.TrimEnd()}\nError: {standardError.TrimEnd()}");
        standardOutput = null;
    }
}
```