# How to properly use await and async in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, process

I am creating a game on Unity which will run a python script in the backend using C#, the script consists of an algorithm which takes time to load and give its output, hence I decided to use asynchronous programming. Here is my code in C#:

```
   public static BERT instance;
   public string valueSaved;
   public void exec()
   {
       p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonFile, fileName)
       {
           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
           UseShellExecute = false,
           CreateNoWindow = true
       };
       p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       p.Start();
       string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       p.WaitForExit();
       valueSaved = output;
   }
   public async void Activate()
   {
      await Task.Run(() => exec());
   }
```

This `Activate()` method is called in another class method:

```
private void runBERT()
    {
       Debug.Log("Executing BERT");
       BERT.instance.Activate();
    }
```

The code seems to be  working fine, as when the `runBERT()` method is called, the `valueSaved` stores the output from the script after its execution, and the game stays fully resumed during this period, otherwise if I directly execute `exec()` method, the game freezes until the script has fully run. However, this is the first time I have applied an `async` method and all I know is that the `await` keyword allows the method to leave the current thread and run in the background, but I will be implementing more of these methods, so I am not sure what I am implementing is fine for the long run, do I need to do anything else? I am just asking this to be on the safe side, so I don't run into errors or exceptions later on. The main thing I want is to store the value returned by the script in the background, which will be called later on.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [process.WaitForExit() asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470256/process-waitforexit-asynchronously)

Answer (score 2):

> the await keyword allows the method to leave the current thread and run in the background

Not really. It's actually the `Task.Run` that makes things run on a thread pool thread.

> do I need to do anything else?

As a general rule, you should [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). Instead of having `Activate` be an `async void` method, it should be an `async Task` method. That way you know when the external process completes (when the task completes).

You can also use `Task<T>` to include a return type by returning `output` instead of setting it to a member variable. And you can treat `Task<T>` as member variables too, i.e., changing the type of `valueSaved` from `string` to `Task<string>`. That would allow all other code to do `await valueSaved;` to asynchronously wait for the process to complete and get its output.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `Activate` method properly asynchronous, without blocking a thread with `Task.Run`, by using the [`Process.WaitForExitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync) method (available from .NET 5 onwards).

```
public async Task<string> ActivateAsync()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = pythonFile;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.Start();
    await p.WaitForExitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return output;
}
```

Usage:

```
string output = await BERT.instance.ActivateAsync();
```

No need for storing the output in a `string` field, as a side-effect, and risking race conditions. The [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) is stored inside the asynchronous `Task<string>`, and it's propagated simply by awaiting the task.