# Launching process in C# Without Distracting Console Window

Tags: c#, process

I figure out how to launch a process. But my problem now is the console window (in this case 7z) pops up frontmost blocking my vision and removing my focus interrupting my sentence or w/e i am doing every few seconds. Its extremely annoying, how do i prevent that from happening. I thought CreateNoWindow solves that but it didnt.

NOTE: sometimes the console needs user input (replace file or not). So hiding it completely may be a problems a well.

This is my current code.

```
void doSomething(...)
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ...;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ...;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: I think I remember CreateNoWindow not working when I used it at my last job.

Answer (score 99):

If I recall correctly, this worked for me

```
Process process = new Process();

// Stop the process from opening a new window
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Setup executable and parameters
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\test.exe"
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--test";

// Go
process.Start();
```

I've been using this from within a C# console application to launch another process, and it stops the application from launching it in a separate window, instead keeping everything in the same window.

Comment: When I set `RedirectStandardOutput ` to `true` I didn't get any output in the default console, commenting that line out gave me output in the default console (I'm creating a console app).

Comment: This seems to cause an issue with `process.WaitForExit`.  I ended up using `process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` instead which appears to work fine.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin WaitForExit may lead to deadlock due to limited buffer size of standard output. The right way to solve it to read the StandardOutput before calling of WaitForExit method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/139604/852284

Answer (score 28):

@galets
In your suggestion, the window is still created, only it begins minimized. This would work better for actually doing what acidzombie24 wanted:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: Outstanding suggestion!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
```

Comment: have tried everything and this is the only thing that has worked

Answer (score 3):

I'll have to double check, but I believe you also need to set `UseShellExecute = false`. This also lets you capture the standard output/error streams.