# Start hidden process C#

Tags: c#, process

Code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351");
```

I want start it hidden, how I can do it?

Comment: ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = "....";
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching process in C# Without Distracting Console Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739101/launching-process-in-c-sharp-without-distracting-console-window)

Comment: @dotctor It can't be a duplicate of that - this question does not launch a console window.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `WindowStyle` property to `Hidden` like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 //Start the process
 Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

one can do like the code below:

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = ....
 psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
 psi.Arguments =...
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
 psi.CreateNoWindow = true; // <- key line
```