# Execute .cmd file from C# without any popup window

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have C# program which finds the Drive Letter of the inserted USB and assign it to a variable `_usbDriveLetter`.

I need to pass the value of `_usbDriveLetter` to a batch file which further executes the `CHKDSK _usbDriveLetter` command.

I have the following code to pass the value of `_usbDriveLetter` and execute the batch file.

```
        string _usbDriveLetter = @"F:\"; //For testing here
        string MyBatchFile = @"<FILEPATH>\chkdsk.cmd";

        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.FileName = MyBatchFile;
        proc.Arguments = usbDriveLetter ;
        Process.Start(proc);
```

**Question:** As soon as the code reach the line to execute the batch, the following window appear to allow the CMD.exe to start. How can I make the execution in background/Silent (at least without any user interaction).

[image]

Comment: Either disable UAC or start the main program with high elevated rights

Comment: I am already elevating the user rights inside the .cmd file. Running my application with elevated rights is not possible.

Comment: If UAC is switched on it requires user interaction, that's the whole point. You will always get a prompt like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739101/launching-process-in-c-sharp-without-distracting-console-window

Comment: @lordkain: Problem is not the console window. My problem is the Popup window where you have to reply in Yes/No as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
Process runprogram = new Process();
                            ProcessStartInfo programinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                            programinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                            programinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            programinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            programinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            programinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                            programinfo.Arguments = " /C \"<FILEPATH>\chkdsk.cmd\"";
                            runprogram.StartInfo = programinfo;
                            runprogram.Start();
```

Also ask for privilege elevation when first running the program.

Comment: thanks, but it won't solve the problem since my problem is not the Console window. My problem is the windows popup message. Apparently, there is no solution to this problem except running my .exe with elevated rights or changing UAC settings.

Comment: @skm I just tested it and it does work?
in your application add a manifest file with the execution level set to highestAvailable and use that code.

Comment: could you provide a sample Manifest for this purpose?

Comment: Heres the manifest - http://pastebin.com/7B6TWEga
As the invoker has elevated privileges whatever the invoker calls will not request higher privilege access as its being executed at a higher level already.

Comment: OP already said the caller is not elevated and that running his application with elevation is not possible.

Comment: Theres absolutely no way of avoiding it unless his caller is elevated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the .cmd to a .exe and setting the property to invisible then run the EXE from C#

Here's the resource to do that - http://www.f2ko.de/en/ob2e.php