# .NET Process.Start() close event from child process

Tags: .net, process

I'm trying to receive the close event from a process, which I start with

```
p1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
AddHandler p1.Exited, AddressOf p1Exited
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p1)
```

However, p1 itself starts a new process p2, then closes immediately and the close event is fired. The process p2 has a GUI and keeps on running. p2 can only be started from p1. I want to get the close event from p2. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is possible to edit `p1` process to wait the completion of `p2` - that will be the simplest solution. In this case you can start `p1` in ['no window' mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739101/launching-process-in-c-sharp-without-distracting-console-window) and wait its completion.

If that is not possible, then you can still find all processes started by `p1` by using [process parent id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way):

```
p1.WaitForExit();
var p1Id = p1.Id;
var subProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => {
    var indexedName = ProcessExtensions.FindIndexedProcessName(p.Id);
    var parentIdCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", indexedName);
    var parentId = (int)parentIdCounter.NextValue();
    return parentId == p1Id;
}).ToArray();
subProcesses.Select(_ => _.Id).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

If you know UI application name and there could not be started more than 1 application for the user, then you can ignore parent id check and just find process by its name.