# Process.Start() get errors from command prompt window

Tags: c#, process, command-prompt

I'm trying to **Start command promt process** with args. Now I want to obtain information about errors if they exist.

```
someProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd, someArgs);
```

Best regards, loviji

Comment: Totally vague question. What kind of error?

Comment: It is not a vague question at all. Comprehensible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other answers are correct. Here is some code you could use:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, args);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
Process someProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
string errors = someProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Note that if the file is not found you won't get an error on standard error. You will get an exception instead.

Comment: Note that the call to ReadToEnd might never terminate. To avoid deadlock use the asynchronous read methods instead. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why/7608823#7608823

Comment: I follow your ans. and got this error in errors (string var.)
'casperjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n
Plz give any solution if exist

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [`StandardError` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[`Process.StandardError` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=VS.100).aspx):

> Gets a stream used to read the error output of the application.

This should do what you want.

**Note**

> To use StandardError, you must set [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=VS.100).aspx) to false, and you must set [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror(v=VS.100).aspx) to true. Otherwise, reading from the StandardError stream throws an exception.