# How to run DOS/CMD/Command Prompt commands from VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, command

The question is self-explanatory. It would be great if the code was one line long (something to do with "`Process.Start("...")`"?). I researched the web but only found old examples and such ones that do not work (at least for me). I want to use this in my class library, to run Git commands (if that helps?).

Comment: maybe start simple with Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\MSPaint.exe") - then once you get that going start trying the Git commands I imagine there much harder with all the additional command line arguments. The other useful tip to help you work out whats wrong, is to read the StandardError, the answer here is a perfect example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709198/process-start-get-errors-from-command-prompt-window

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try this method:

```
Public Class MyUtilities
    Shared Sub RunCommandCom(command as String, arguments as String, permanent as Boolean) 
        Dim p as Process = new Process() 
        Dim pi as ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() 
        pi.Arguments = " " + if(permanent = true, "/K" , "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments 
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe" 
        p.StartInfo = pi 
        p.Start() 
    End Sub
End Class
```

call, for example, in this way:

```
MyUtilities.RunCommandCom("DIR", "/W", true)
```

**EDIT:** For the multiple command on one line the key are the & | && and || command connectors

- **A & B** → execute command A, then execute command B.
- **A | B** → execute command A, and redirect all it's output into the
  input of command B.
- **A && B** → execute command A, evaluate the errorlevel after running
  Command A, and if the exit code (errorlevel) is 0, only then execute
  command B.
- **A || B** → execute Command A, evaluate the exit code of this command
  and if it's anything but 0, only then execute command B.

Comment: Hello! I used this code (https://gist.github.com/2465024) and when I run your command (I changed the name to "`runCommand`" and used that - so that's not the problem!), I get a "`Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.`" error. Any ideas why?

Comment: BTW, it works when it's in the same class, however I used it in a Class Library, which I imported to my Windows Forms project. Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Also, is there a way to run multiple commands at once. Something like "`Hide cmd, run first command, hide cmd, run second command, show cmd.`".

Comment: For the class library problem: Yes, of course, inside a class library you need to declare the method Shared if you want to use without creating an instance. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 17):

You Can try This To Run Command Then `cmd` Exits

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c YourCode")
```

You Can try This To Run The Command And Let `cmd` Wait For More Commands

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k YourCode")
```

Answer (score 6):

I was inspired by Steve's answer but thought I'd add a bit of flare to it.
I like to do the work up front of writing extension methods so later I have less work to do calling the method.

For example with the modified version of Steve's answer below, instead of making this call...

`MyUtilities.RunCommandCom("DIR", "/W", true)`

I can actually just type out the command and call it from my strings like this...

*Directly in code.*

`Call "CD %APPDATA% & TREE".RunCMD()`

OR

*From a variable.*

```
Dim MyCommand = "CD %APPDATA% & TREE"
MyCommand.RunCMD()
```

OR

*From a textbox.*

`textbox.text.RunCMD(WaitForProcessComplete:=True)`

---

Extension methods will need to be placed in a Public Module and carry the `<Extension>` attribute over the sub. You will also want to add `Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices` to the top of your code file.

There's plenty of info on SO about Extension Methods if you need further help.

---

**Extension Method**

```
Public Module Extensions
''' <summary>
''' Extension method to run string as CMD command.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="command">[String] Command to run.</param>
''' <param name="ShowWindow">[Boolean](Default:False) Option to show CMD window.</param>
''' <param name="WaitForProcessComplete">[Boolean](Default:False) Option to wait for CMD process to complete before exiting sub.</param>
''' <param name="permanent">[Boolean](Default:False) Option to keep window visible after command has finished. Ignored if ShowWindow is False.</param>
<Extension>
Public Sub RunCMD(command As String, Optional ShowWindow As Boolean = False, Optional WaitForProcessComplete As Boolean = False, Optional permanent As Boolean = False)
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    pi.Arguments = " " + If(ShowWindow AndAlso permanent, "/K", "/C") + " " + command
    pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    pi.CreateNoWindow = Not ShowWindow
    If ShowWindow Then
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Else
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    End If
    p.StartInfo = pi
    p.Start()
    If WaitForProcessComplete Then Do Until p.HasExited : Loop
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub systemcmd(ByVal cmd As String)
    Shell("cmd /c """ & cmd & """", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public line, counter As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        counter += 1
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter a DNS address to ping")
        Else
            'line = ":start" + vbNewLine
            'line += "ping " + TextBox1.Text
            'MsgBox(line)
            Dim StreamToWrite As StreamWriter
            StreamToWrite = New StreamWriter("C:\Desktop\Ping" + counter + ".bat")
            StreamToWrite.Write(":start" + vbNewLine + _
                                "Ping -t " + TextBox1.Text)
            StreamToWrite.Close()
            Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Desktop\Ping" + counter + ".bat"
            p.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works as well

Comment: Not my answer, and not saying this is or isn't a good answer, but if you down vote please explain why. It benefits others to know why this was not considered a good solution.