# dos cmd \cmd prompt vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

i used this example to open a command prompt from within vb.net 2010

[lnk to stackoverflow document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261521/how-to-run-dos-cmd-command-prompt-commands-from-vb-net)

the command prompt opens as expected and i can do directories open commands like regedit etc. without an issue

but what i really want is tftp.exe when i look for it it does not show up, when doing a dir it is not listed when type tftp at command prompt i get the to recognzed command

when comparing to a normal command prompt by type cmd at the run line i can see it in the windows\system32 folder

also when i do a dir from normal command prompt and compare to dir from the cmd prompt opened by vb.net there is a 400+ number of files difference out of close to 3000 files

trying to find out why i cant see all the files here is the actul code i used

```
Private Sub Button30_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button30.Click
        Dim command As String = "tftp -i 192.168.10.177 put test1.bin"
        Dim arguments As String = ""
        Dim permanent As Boolean = True
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        pi.Arguments = " " + If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        p.StartInfo = pi
        p.Start()
    End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this. Why not just have your code directly call tftp.exe?

Comment: i am if you look at the code it is calling tftp -i 192.168.10.177 put test1.bin, and it does not see it i get the command not found so i tried to execute manually and it cant find it either. unless there is another way i should be trying to call it.

Comment: You don't need to use cmd.exe just run the tftp command directly. Your approach is very convoluted and unnecessary.

Comment: i took it 1 step further or lessoned the code to just dim oprocess as process and next line oprocess.start("notepad.exe") and notepad opens but if i change notepad.exe to tftp.exe i get a files not found error. and both files are in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the answer, it is becuase i am running 64bit windows and when its looking for the tftp.exe it is actually looking in the syswow64 directory and tftp.exe is not in that directory.

since i have this running and compiled for x86 and not 64bit here is the work around

```
Public Declare Function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32" (ByRef oldvalue As Long) As Boolean
```

then

```
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(0)
```

after adding tthis to my code the tftp upload works flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very convuluted approch you are taking, but to answer your question directly, you probably need to set the working directory like so:

```
pi.WorkingDirectory = "c:\windows\system32"
```

I have to say though, you might want to reconsider the whole approach of opening a DOS window for the user to type commands. Doesn't see very user friendly.

Comment: i dont want the box to stay open when it is working if i change the command on line 2 to somethign else in that directory it runs ie xcopy . again only leaving cmd prompt open till i find why it doesnt see the tftp.exe file

Comment: i tried addign working directory same result. the wierd thing is if i do a dir tftp*.* nothing is found but if i do dir tftp*.* from a normal cmd prompt it is there

Comment: i took it 1 step further or lessoned the code to just dim oprocess as process and next line oprocess.start("notepad.exe") and notepad opens but if i change notepad.exe to tftp.exe i get a files not found error. and both files are in the same directory