# Install Curl during Docker Image Build Process and better understand the build process

Tags: vb.net, docker, curl, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

This is a linked question to my previous question [RUN cmd and execute curl command in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346193/run-cmd-and-execute-curl-command-in-vb-net/69347640?noredirect=1#comment122573674_69347640).

I have a vb.net very small application that makes a api call and prints the response.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
 Dim curlApplicationPath = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "curl.exe")
 Dim arguments = $"/k {curlApplicationPath} --location --request GET http://ip:port/"
        
     Process.Start("cmd.exe", arguments)

    End Sub 
End Module
```

I want now to run this application in docker (for windows).
This is what I wrote in dockerfile.

```
From mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
From curlimages/curl:latest
From mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.6.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Release .
ENTRYPOINT ["CurlCall.exe"]
```

and build the image by running the following command

```
docker build -t curlcall .
```

Upon running the following command

```
docker run --rm -it curlcall
```

My expected response was hello-world, which I get when I am running my vb.net application outside of docker.
But I get no response at all. Then I logged into the interactive session of the image by

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=cmd.exe curlcall
```

and tried to run curl google.com and got the response that

```
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then I copied the curl executeable manually in the docker image and CD into

```
C:\test\curl-7.79.1-win64-mingw\bin>curl
```

and ran this command and it works as expected.

```
curl --location --request GET http://ip:port/
```

I think this is the main problem that Curl is not configured during the build process, and I search around but couldn't find a way to configure CURL via dockerfile.

I hope I explained the question well.
Could anyone please help me figure out the situation?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There's no way to combine images; each `FROM` line starts a new image from the named base image.  So you have a plain .NET Runtime image and you need to install Curl into it in some other way.

Comment: (Not a .NET expert at all, but is there a C#-native HTTP client you can use, instead of shelling out to `curl`?)

Comment: Okay. I will take into account the first commend, I didn't know that we can't combine the images. 
And secondly I have many curl commands and translating them into httprequests would be a lot of work so the idea is to simply run curl commands.