# How to run DOS/CMD/Command Prompt commands from VB.NET and want to hold its terminal output for few seconds?

Tags: vb.net

How to run DOS/CMD/Command Prompt commands from VB.NET and want to hold its terminal output for few seconds. After that it should be close automatically.

Comment: Vb.net and VB6 are different languages. Please remove the vb6 tag from your post!

Comment: What have you already tried?  How is it failing?  You should start by looking at various process and console documentation in the MSDN docs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goal, there could be multiple solutions to this request.

This SO post details how you can run a command from cmd.exe, passing arguments.

[How to run DOS/CMD/Command Prompt commands from VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261521/how-to-run-dos-cmd-command-prompt-commands-from-vb-net)

Another idea, depending on the goal, would be to save the cmd as a batch file or similar, where you could have a pause or timed wait before the cmd window closes.

Then you could call the batch file from vb.net

I don't want to dive too deep into how each of these would be done without knowing more about the goal at hand.