# Why is my process's Exited method not being called?

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code, but why is the `ProcessExited` method never called? It is the same if I don't a use Windows shell (`startInfo.UseShellExecute = false`).

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = path;
startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Util.GetParentDirectory(path, 1);

try
{
     Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
     correctionProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited);                   

     correctionProcess.WaitForExit();

     status = true;
}
```

.....

```
internal void ProcessExited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      //print out here
}
```

Answer (score 286, accepted):

In order to receive a callback on `Exited` event, the [**`EnableRaisingEvents`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) must be set to true.

```
Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
correctionProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
correctionProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited);
```

Comment: correctionProcess.WaitForExit(), without this function this code is not working for me

Comment: One small tip (esp for non C# experts): don't `Close()` the process! I've encountered intermittent issue with the Exit handler due to a misguided effort at resource management. The code in question called `Process.Close()` after `Process.Start(startInfo)`, rather than allowing the GC to collect it in due course. Easy mistake if your background is non-GC languages (e.g. C/C++).

Comment: Great. Thanks. I also want to remark that assignment of `EnableRaisingEvents` and `EventHandlers` must be done exactly after the `Process.Start()`. It wont work otherwise.

Comment: @Doruk I can set `EnableRaisingEvents=true` before calling `Process.Start()` and it works fine.

Answer (score 34):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx):

> The Exited event indicates that the
>   associated process exited. This
>   occurrence means either that the
>   process terminated (aborted) or
>   successfully closed. This event can
>   occur only if the value of the
>   EnableRaisingEvents property is true.

Have you set that property to true?

Comment: It is a very un-idomatic flag, too (what's the use anyway, if I don't want the event, I don't subscribe to it!)

Comment: Not very intuitive. Should clearly state in each event description that it requires this flag to be set.

Comment: It's indeed not very intuitive but the property needs to be set so that the application can register to be notified about the target process' exit through the Win32 Api.

Answer (score 22):

You must set `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`.

Answer (score 21):

Set correctionProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true

Answer (score 21):

I've come across examples that place `new Process()` in a `using` clause.  Do not do that if you want to use the `Exited` feature.  The `using` clause destroys the instance along with any event handles on `Exited`.

This...

```
using(var process = new Process())
{
   // your logic here
}
```

Should be this...

```
var process = new Process();
```

Comment: I've noticed that too. Strangely enough, OutputDataReceived events work fine. Or may be they occur so fast that go before execution in the main thread comes to End Using.