# How can I keep the state of a boolean across button clicks?

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to write a program that can be used to launch another program. I have a button, and when it's clicked, I'd like to start a program, and also record that the program has been launched. When I go to start a new program, I'd like to first check that I haven't already started the program—and if I have, close the existing instance first (so at most one instance of the program will exist at a time).

I've already written the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool status = false;
    if (status != true)
    {
        status = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Test\\Test.exe");
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, if I click on the button, the variable is set to `false` as you can see on the first line. How I can do it correctly? Also, how I do return 0 if status is set on true?

Comment: Please read up about scope. PS. What do you think the value of status should be after the line `bool status = false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of the `bool` variable outside the method if you would like to preserve its value across invocations:

```
bool status = false;
Process myProcess;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (status != true) {
        myProcess = new Process()
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        status = true;
        // Start a process to print a file and raise an event when done.
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Test\\Test.exe";
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
        myProcess.Start();
    }
}

private void Process_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    status = false;
}
```

Now the diagnostic message will come up only once per life time of your object. Once the process exits, the `status` is reset to `false`, letting you click the button again.

Also note that since the button does not do anything after the status is set to `true`, it is a good idea to disable it to avoid confusing end-users.

Comment: Additionally, you may consider disabling the button, since it won't do anything anyway

Comment: Oh, I've tried the same thing, but my problem was, that I've added directly under "using System.Windows.Forms;"

Comment: Thanks for your help, any way to give you reputation points or something similar here ?

Comment: @JustMe.77 If the answer works, you can accept it by clicking the grey check mark next to it. The checkmark becomes active 15 minutes after you ask the question, so you if you would like to do it, you would need to wait for five more minutes. Good luck with your project!

Comment: But I've another question, hope you can answer it:

Comment: Sorry, for the multiple comments, I tried to add a new line with enter but it sends my reply :D My other question is: I'd like to set the status to false again if I close the program. How I can do that exactly? Thanks for your help

Comment: The status is false upon start. 'bool status = false' declares a new variable which is set to false upon start of your application. What exactly do you mean?!

Comment: What do you mean guys? I don't understand it well, I've just started today with it.

Comment: The current code look like this:  bool status = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (status != true)
            {
                status = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Test\\Test.exe");
            }
            
        } Why is the button useless? With the button, I start the .exe I want

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've opened the Test.exe, if I click again on it, it won't open (that's good), but if I close the Test.exe and try to reopen it with the button, its not working since the status is still set on true. That's why I am asking for a methode to check if I closed the program, so I can set the status to false again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not closing the application, only the Test.exe which is going to be executed if I click on the button. The Test.exe is not listed in the Task Manager once I click on the X Button.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hey, thanks for your answer again. My current code look like this: http://pastebin.com/TcVzZr9k But I'm getting 3 times following error code: CS0103. Also, what do you mean with your last sentence?  Why should I disable the button? I want that the user is anytime able to disable / enable the Test.exe.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm now getting following error code on the new line CS0246. Current code look like: http://pastebin.com/icRs5vWV

Comment: @JustMe.77 Your latest sample is missing a `using System.Diagnostics;` for `myProcess`. Here are more details at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx).

Comment: The Errors are gone now @JedBurke, but I cant open the Test.exe again once I've closed the Test.exe.. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: @JustMe.77 Try moving the declaration of `myProcess` outside the `button1_Click` method to see if the callback would start happening.

Comment: @JustMe.77 You need to set `myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` Mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4504208) citing [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Indeed it is, I only learned about it now myself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Move it to where exactly? I'm getting errors if I move it like this: http://pastebin.com/GBgKMw3K

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and Jedburke It work's like this, I've added myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents  = true;. Thanks a lot to you two guys, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring the variable inside the click_button event, so the variable cannot be reached outside the method "click_button"

Try with something like this

```
bool status = false;
int ChangeStatus()
{
    if(status!=true)
    {
        status = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Test\\Test.exe");
        return 0;
    }
  return 1; //if the status is false it will return 1 or the value you want
}
```

Then in the Button_Click event you should add

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //I don't know where you will display or save the value (0 or 1) I will assign it in a variable
    var result = ChangeStatus();
 }
```

Hope it could help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried like this (don't know how to paste it as code here, so I'll use pastebin) http://pastebin.com/C0nX9cTj But I can't reopen Test.exe, once I close it. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "reopen".
So you want that your app read the last status?
So if I set the status "true" and I close the app, then when I open the app again you want the status to be true?

Comment: I want it like this: Open Test.exe -> Status is on true. Then, if I close Test.exe, the status should be false so I can open it again. Because currently, I wouldn't be able to open the Test.exe, even if the Test.exe has been closed.