# How to get the cmd.exe output as a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2015, cmd

I tried to get the output of passed argument in the cmd.exe via c# code. But when the code `string outw = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();` executing takes more and more time. Here my command prompt arguments work perfectly.

Here is my code

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("git init && git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.company.com/test2.git && git push gitlab --delete branchname");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("git remote remove gitlab");
        string outw = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();//Here my code strucks
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Where I made the mistake? I waited for more than 30 min but I did not get the output in the `string outw`. How could I get the output test as a string in `string outw`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process.start: how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Comment: Trying to work with `cmd.exe` interactively feels like it could easily be a lot harder than just launching each process directly...

Comment: What Jon says is true, unless you need some of the special features of the Command Prompt shell. That isn't true in this case; in fact, with git, the Windows-isms of cmd.exe are likely to be more annoying than helpful.

Comment: You forgot to tell cmd.exe to quit running.  So ReadToEnd() never completes.  There are better ways to do this, but sending "exit" should be the simple solution.

Comment: I suspect the answer would be pretty easy to see if you didn't use `CreateNoWindow`. In particular, I suspect that cmd doesn't exit, given that you didn't tell it to. Also note that some git commands don't use the standard I/O streams, so don't be too surprised if you get garbage out of some of them (the ones in your code should be fine IIRC),

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160187/standardoutput-readtoend-hangs

Comment: Also, just use LibGit2Sharp.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I send the "exit" ?

Comment: The exact same why you sent "git".