# How to forcibly close Process in c# after some period of time?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I got following code

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process capp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    capp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    capp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
    capp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    capp.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    capp.StartInfo.FileName = "app.exe";
    capp.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i -v -mj";
    capp.Start();

    consoleOutput = capp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + capp.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    if (!capp.WaitForExit(10000)) capp.Kill();
```

and problem, if outside application works correctly it takes less than 10 seconds for it to complete its tasks. If it stop/hung for some reason despite of using

```
    if (!capp.WaitForExit(10000)) capp.Kill();
```

as suggested in some other topic, it keeps working. Above line seem not to work at all in my case, i guess it has to do with fact i read StandardOutput and StandardError. How to fix my code to make reading output and WaitForExit() to work aside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't always read from **both** `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` the buffers can fill causing the process to block.

You first try to read `StandardOutput` to the end. The process you run might be writing a lot of data to `StandardError` until it blocks and can't write more. Then this results in *your* application blocking as it doesn't even start reading from `StandardError` until the process closes its `StandardOutput`. This creates a deadlock and neither process will continue.

I suggest you use the solution I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608823/61974).  It uses asynchronous reads to read from both `StandardOutput` and `StandardError`, avoiding deadlocks.