# Slow performance using mysqldump from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to launch mysqldump from my C# console application using this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("mysqldump", "avisdb -uroot -p" + cs.Password);
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procInfo;
proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();

File.Delete("dump.sql");
StreamWriter dump = File.AppendText("dump.sql");
dump.Write(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
dump.Flush();
dump.Close();
```

it works great when my db is empty, but it takes forever when DB is populated... Launching the command via cmd it takes just a few seconds. I can see it stalls on proc.WaitForExit()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WaitForExit() is not the problem.. I wonder what your SQL looks like.. if the db is empty.. then one must ask..what is it that you are trying to do..??? I would also suggest that you free the resources of the objects where you Create new Object.. also where is dump variable being declared..??

Comment: for 'empty' I mean with about a dozen record across 8 tables, for 'populated' I mean about 10 thousand records in one table, 300 in another and 100 across the remaining tables... if I launch mysqldump via command line it takes a few seconds to dump a populated DB, via C#... well, it has been running for two hours and it hasn't finished yet... the dump streamwriter is declared on the second line after WaitForExit

Answer (score 1):

Calling WaitForExit() before StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() can result in a deadlock condition, call ReadToEnd() first and you should be fine.

Details from MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

> The code example avoids a deadlock condition by
>   calling p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd before p.WaitForExit. A deadlock
>   condition can result if the parent process calls p.WaitForExit before
>   p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd and the child process writes enough text to
>   fill the redirected stream. The parent process would wait indefinitely
>   for the child process to exit. The child process would wait
>   indefinitely for the parent to read from the full StandardOutput
>   stream.

SO post regarding this issue,
[ProcessStartInfo hanging on "WaitForExit"? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why)