# How to copy a MySql database schema using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-schema

I'm trying to use C# & MySql in order to copy an empty table (recreate the Schema really). The structure looks like this:

```
> TableTemplate (schema)
    + Tables
        > FirstTable    (table)
        > second table  (table)
        > ...

> SomeOtherTable
    + Tables
        > ...
```

What I would like is to copy the `TableTemplate` into a new Schema with the user name.

The first obvious path to oblivion was trying `CREATE TABLE @UserName LIKE TableTemplate`, swiftly learning that sql parameters are supposed to be used for values and not table names (all hail jon skeet, again: [How to pass a table as parameter to MySqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6386093/1698987)).

So that leaves us with manual validation of the user names in order to build the table names ([robert's a prime example](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Next, it seems that even `CREATE TABLE UserID LIKE TableTemplate;` won't work (even from MySQL Workbench), since `TableTemplate` isn't a table.

So It's down to writing a loop that will create a table `LIKE` each table in `TableTemplate`, after creating a `UserID` Schema (after manual validation of that string), or trying other options like dumping the database and creating a new one, as seen in these questions:

- [C# and mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16483871/1698987)
- [Slow performance using mysqldump from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9521644/1698987)

But I would prefer avoid running a process, dumping the database, and creating it from there every time I add a user.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using something like this, in a method where `aName` is passed for the table name:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ;", aName), connection))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          // Create the database with the given user name

    // Building the sql query that will return a "create table" per table in some_db template DB.
    cmd.CommandText = (string.Format("SELECT CONCAT (\"CREATE TABLE {0}.\", TABLE_NAME ,\" "
                                       + "LIKE some_other_db.\", TABLE_NAME ) as creation_sql "
                                       + "FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'some_db';"
                                    , aName));

    try     // Building the inner tables "create table" sql strings
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
                createInnerTablesList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException mysql_ex) { ... } // handle errors 

    foreach (var sql_insert_query in createInnerTablesList)
    {
        try                         // Insert the tables into the user database
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql_insert_query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... } // handle errors 
    }
}
```

The reasons for using `LIKE` vs `AS` like Jungsu suggested is that even though the `AS` will create the tables, it will not keep any of the constraints and keys defined (primary key, etc).

Using the `LIKE` will replicate them with the constraints.

I'm still not too happy about this, since I feel I'm missing something though ...

Answer (score 1):

I think `mysqldump` would be better. but if you want to do in one process. try this.

```
SELECT
   CONCAT ("CREATE TABLE SomeOtherTable.", 
       TABLE_NAME ," AS SELECT * FROM TableTemplate.", TABLE_NAME
   ) as creation_sql
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TableTemplate';
```

the output will be like

> CREATE TABLE SomeOtherTable.tbl_name AS SELECT * FROM TableTemplate.tbl_name;

then iterate result and execute `CREATE TABLE ....`

Comment: Upvoted, and added an answer for what worked for me. Thanks for the help nevertheless.