# Clone MySql table structure in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using MySQL.Data 6.9.9 library and .Net framework 4.5 to work with MySQL server in C# code.

There is a table1 with rows and I want to create the table2 with the same structure as table1 in same database but without rows.

Please advice how to create it?

Comment: What have you tried already? Can't you just use a query to create the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL can do that out of the box.

```
CREATE TABLE
 table
LIKE 
 table
```

> Use CREATE TABLE ... LIKE to create an empty table based on the
>   definition of another table, including any column attributes and
>   indexes defined in the original table:

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-like.html

Comment: @borobos Mark it as the solution if this the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually:

```
CREATE TABLE table2  LIKE table1;
```

And then update your edmx model if you use "Database First" approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not use "Database First" approach but the usage of MySqlCommand with this create syntax is that what I needed.

Also, found the related https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320118/2679054