# How to read to end process output asynchronously in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process

I have problem with reading the output of one Process asynchronously in C#. 
I found some other similar questions on this site but they don't really help me.
Here is what I do:

1. Make new process
2. Set startinfo
   -FileName, Arguments, CreateNoWindow(true), UseShellExecute(false), RedirectStandardOutput(true)
3. Add event handler to OutputDataReceived;
4. Start process, BeginOutputReadLine and then WaitForExit().

It works fine but the output of the started process writes some percents(`%`) which I want to get but I can't since my code reads line by line and the percents don't show up.

Example:

```
%0,%1...%100
Finished.
```

My output:

```
%0
Finished.
```

Here is the current code of my program:

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    sBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
}

static void CommandExecutor()
{
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = /*path of the program*/,
            Arguments = /*arguments*/,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
    };

    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);

    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the appenline method to see how many times it is hit?  In the console app, do the percentages overwrite eachother or are the continuous?

Comment: The percentages overwrite. I will put a breakpoint to see what will happen...

Comment: It isn't called BeginOutputRead**Line** by accident.  The program doesn't output any lines.  And it normally doesn't output anything when output is redirected unless the program explicitly calls flush().  You can't fix this.

Answer (score 12):

`Process.WaitForExit()` will wait until the asynchronous output / error stream reading finished. Unfortunately this is not true for `Process.WaitForExit(timeout)` overload. This is what the `Process` class does internally:

//...

```
finally
{
    if (processWaitHandle != null)
    {
        processWaitHandle.Close();
    }
    if (this.output != null && milliseconds == -1)
    {
        this.output.WaitUtilEOF();
    }
    if (this.error != null && milliseconds == -1)
    {
        this.error.WaitUtilEOF();
    }
    this.ReleaseProcessHandle(safeProcessHandle);
}
```

... So it will wait for the async reads only if there was no timeout! 
To fix it simply call the `parameterless WaitForExit()` after `WaitForExit(timeout)` returned true:

// ...

```
if (process.WaitForExit( 10 * 1000 ) && process.WaitForExit() )
{
 // Process'es OutputDataReceived / ErrorDataReceived callbacks will not be called again, EOF streams reached
}
else
{
   throw new Exception("timeout");
}
```

For details read the remarks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.110%29

Comment: This is the proper way to fix this issue. Should be the official answer.

Comment: This doesn't work if the process doesn't complete.  For example if you want to isolate code in a process because it can enter a zombie state, this approach will stay on the WaitForExit() statement forever :-(

Answer (score 10):

It seems that reading stream output asynchronously is a bit broken - not all the data is read before the process exits. Even if you call `Process.WaitForExit()` and even if you then call `Process.Close()` (or `Dispose()`) you can still get a lot of data afterwards. See http://alabaxblog.info/2013/06/redirectstandardoutput-beginoutputreadline-pattern-broken/ for a full write-up, but the solution is basically to use synchronous methods. To avoid a deadlock, though, you have to call one of them on another thread:

```
using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
{
    // Read stderr synchronously (on another thread)

    string errorText = null;
    var stderrThread = new Thread(() => { errorText = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); });
    stderrThread.Start();

    // Read stdout synchronously (on this thread)

    while (true)
    {
        var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;

        // ... Do something with the line here ...
    }

    process.WaitForExit();
    stderrThread.Join();

    // ... Here you can do something with errorText ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked for me. Silly broken BeginOutputReadLine

Comment: @EM0, the link seems broken.

Comment: Not the proper solution. Check @Sly answer.

Comment: Sly's answer brings up a big "gotcha", for sure, but neither the question nor my answer uses the `WaitForExit(timeout)`, so I'm not sure why this is "not the proper solution" to the original question. Could you elaborate on what is wrong with it @Deathicon?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that are getting in the way of it...

The console app is probably using "\b" backspace to overwrite the percentage, its maybe not flushing to the `stdout` stream after every write, and the `BeginOutputReadLine` presumably waits for the end of line before giving you data.

See how you get on with reading `process.StandardOutput.BaseStream` via `BeginRead` (this code isn't proper **async** and the "\b"s will need processed differently if your putting progress in a form):

```
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            var ar = myProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 256, null, null);
            ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            var bytesRead = myProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            }
            else
            {
                myProcess.WaitForExit();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `StreamReader` on `process.StandardOutput`, and the using the `Read()` method ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.streamreader.read(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I have tried this but it shows the output when the process finishes and I can't get the percents...