# C# get Realtime output Youtube-dl

Tags: c#, powershell

I have searched a lot but nothing worked...this code gives me the result when the console ends.
but I want real-time output!

- is there any way to achieve this?

```
string text1 = "C:/Program Files/Sycho_DL/Downloader.exe -f 242+250 --merge-output-format mp4 -o " + DPath + "/%(title)s.%(ext)s ";
string me2me1 = text1 + urlBoxText2;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = @"C:/Program Files/Sycho_DL/Downloader.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = me2me1;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    richbox1.Text = line;
}
```

Comment: There are events for that, but for starters, you can just move `process.WaitForExit()` after the loop.

Comment: @PMF Still gets the last command after the process ends.

Comment: You mean, the last line is only printed after the process exits? There might be a small delay, but that's typically not noticeable, unless you're using the debugger.

Comment: @PMF nooo it's downloading the video.... and after everything finishes it gives me the last code

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533070/how-to-read-to-end-process-output-asynchronously-in-c help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.Diagnostics.Process` APIs built into .NET can be difficult to use. I'd suggest using a library that wraps them; my favourite is [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap). It has a few different ways to execute external processes, but the "Pull-based event stream" that returns an `IAsyncEnumerable` would work well here, something like:

```cs
using CliWrap;
using CliWrap.EventStream;

var cmd = Cli.Wrap("ExePathGoesHere").WithArguments("ArgumentsGoHere");

await foreach (var cmdEvent in cmd.ListenAsync())
{
    switch (cmdEvent)
    {
        case StandardOutputCommandEvent stdOut:
            // to do: append stdOut.Text to your text box
            break;
        case StandardErrorCommandEvent stdErr:
            // to do: append stdErr.Text to your text box
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am testing it...but gives this error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuNvv.png

Comment: You will need to make the function that is calling this async. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async