# NLog Logger.Trace hangs forever

Tags: c#, windows-services, nlog

I have a Windows service application running under my username (installed via installutil).

Here are my start/stop event overloads:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Fatal("...");
        throw;
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    logger.Trace("service stopped.");
}
```

`logger` is an NLog Logger instance, obtained like this:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Here is my `NLog.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

    <!-- 
  See http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="Debugger" name="debugger_target" />
        <target xsi:type="Chainsaw" name="chainsaw_target" address="udp4://localhost:4141"/>
        <!--
        <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
        -->
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="chainsaw_target"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then in a specific case I want to add a console log:

```
    private static void InitializeLogConfiguration()
    {
        var logConfig = LogManager.Configuration ?? new LoggingConfiguration();

        var consoleRule = new ColoredConsoleTarget("logConsole");
        consoleRule.Layout = Layout.FromString("${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${newline}${message:withexception=true}${newline}");
        logConfig.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, consoleRule);
        logConfig.DefaultCultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        LogManager.Configuration = logConfig;
    }
```

The service starts up just fine, and the debugger attaches as one would expect, and if I continue from there the service completes its start.

If I then stop the service, a breakpoint in `OnStop` hits, but when I try to continue over the `logger.Trace` call, it hangs indefinitely and becomes unresponsive to the service container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was seeing this happening due to a known issue with the blocking calls to [StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput) where combinations of reading and writing to redirected console can deadlock. If you are using NLog to write to a console and you need to read from that console in the same thread I recommend trying the [AsyncTargetWrapper](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_Wrappers_AsyncTargetWrapper.htm). This will run logging operations on a different thread so your application can move on with it's own life and not get stuck waiting around for a task that never returns.

You can add it to your `nlog.config` by adding `async="true"` to your `targets` section like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

    <!-- 
  See http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
    <targets async="true">
        <target xsi:type="Debugger" name="debugger_target" />
        <target xsi:type="Chainsaw" name="chainsaw_target" address="udp4://localhost:4141"/>
        <!--
        <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
        -->
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="chainsaw_target"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Of if you are defining the console log in code, like I was, you can wrap the target like this:

```
LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(c => c.ForLogger(LogLevel.Trace).WriteToConsole().WithAsync());
```

You still have to be careful to avoid the [issues seen in process redirected console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why).

Comment: If you have some callstacks from the experienced deadlock situation, then you are wellcome to open an issue at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues

Comment: Ok, thanks. For readers of the future, it happened here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5236