# How to run an command installed through NPM in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, postman, newman

I have a simple Azure Function written in c#, it calls newman, a tool installed through NPM. it works fine locally, but newman is not recognized after deploying to Azure. I installed newman from Kudu console, and I can run newman from Kudu console without any problem, not not when I call it from Azure function:

*'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would'nt it be better if you write the `azure-function` in `node` so that you can directly make use of the npm runner ?

But never mind a quick search landed me on [this blog](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/running-npm-scripts-from-a-dotnet-core-process) the guy has an generic example for running npm scripts from c# app.

Also both of these stackoverflow answers do help too

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583148/8368871

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603821/8368871