# process.startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput gives exception and process.waitforexit() hangs C# application

Tags: c#, process, processstartinfo, waitforexit

using process i am getting an exception while using                  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
the exception is below 
"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."

i am using process.WaitForExit which hangs my application gui so i used process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); before WaitForExit  as per MSDN but now my process run for infinite time and gives above exception in log file and GUI also hangs.

```
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);


                string strArguments = ""; 

                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"appname.bat";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = strArguments;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                process.Start();


                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
```

I am not getting where am i lacking or where is the error in the code... Even i have tried time out in waitforexit also but didn't get success.

Comment: You can specify a timeout on the WaitForExit()

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", args.Data);
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

process.WaitForExit();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

You should try this.
Change sequence of code.