# ContinueWith() doesn't execute until host process ends

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Our team has been having an issue where `ContinueWith()` won't run until the host process is shutting down. For example, the code below has been running just fine in production for a year. But since we've started using newer versions of our framework, we've had this issue.

When running this code, `this.Sites = GetViewableSites();` runs and then nothing else happens when debugging. After hitting `F10`, the debugger returns to the UI. Only after the user closes the UI does the `ContinueWith()` execute.

```
this.PerformBusyAction(() =>
{
    this.Sites = GetViewableSites();
}, ViewModelResource.LoadingForm)
.ContinueWith(originatingTask =>
{
    // ** This doesn't execute until the user closes the UI **
    if (originatingTask.Exception == null)
    {
        PerformPostSuccessfulInitialization();
        return;
    }
    PerformPostUnsuccessfulInitialization(originatingTask.Exception.InnerExceptions);
});
```

For completeness, here is `PerformBusyAction()`:

```
    protected Task PerformBusyAction(Action action, string busyMessage)
    {
        this.BusyMessage = busyMessage;
        this.IsBusy = true;  // Let the UI know we're busy, so it can display a busy indicator

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.IsBusy = false;
                this.BusyMessage = String.Empty;
            }
        });

        return task;
    }
```

Any idea what would cause this? We can say the culprit is our framework, and it may be, but we haven't been able to figure out how this can possibly happen. To get around the issue, we just stopped using `ContinueWith()` and put all the code in the first section/task.

**Edit**

Perhaps this is a bug? There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16218470/279516), although it's with `Console.ReadKey()`.

**Edit 2 - Call stack immediately after calling GetViewableSites()**

> Not Flagged   >   6324    6   Worker Thread   Worker
>   Thread    Acme.Mes.Apps.Derating.ViewModels.Controls.GlobalTabControlViewModel.Initialize.AnonymousMethod__9  Normal
>                         Acme.Mes.Apps.Derating.ViewModels.dll!Acme.Mes.Apps.Derating.ViewModels.Controls.GlobalTabControlViewModel.Initialize.AnonymousMethod__9()
>   Line 361
>                         Acme.Mes.Client.dll!Acme.Mes.Client.Mvvm.MvvmTools.ViewModelBase.PerformBusyAction.AnonymousMethod__c()
>   Line 494 + 0xe bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() + 0x49 bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() + 0x2e bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object
>   obj) + 0x15 bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) + 0xcb bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) + 0xb3 bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   + 0x7 bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x149
>   bytes
>                         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>   + 0x5 bytes
>                         [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: Have you tried with `Task`s that don't use any UI controls?

Comment: There are no UI controls here. This is all view model and base class stuff.

Comment: Are you able to produce small but complete sample that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: What does `IsBusy = false` do? That looks like it would hit the UI...

Comment: We've been through this before as I remember.  Same recipe, you really do have to post the stack trace of the thread.  Nobody can see with "GetViewableSites" might be doing.

Comment: @JonSkeet `IsBusy` is a property on the view model, and the view binds to that property.

Comment: @BobHorn: Right. So the claim that "there are no UI controls here" isn't really correct. In particular, changing those properties on a non-UI thread will end up trying to change the UI elements on a non-UI thread, unless your view model is explicitly marshalling.

Comment: @HansPassant I posted the code for `GetViewableSites()`. I don't think it's relevant here. Like I said, I can step all the way through it without issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet So maybe that's it then... A bound property is changing on a non-UI thread. Not sure why that would cause the issue, but maybe that's it. This application did work in the past when it was only running on .NET 4.0.

Comment: That *may* be it, but I wouldn't like to say for sure. I'd expect an exception to be thrown - at least when running under the debugger.

Comment: That's just more code that doesn't tell me what is really going on.  The stack trace of the thread shows why it is blocking, it is on top of the trace.  Use the debugger force Luke.

Comment: No exception. I hit F10 and then nothing. At that point control switches from VS to the WPF UI.

Comment: WPF marshals scalar property changes to UI thread for you. More a hunch than anything else: please try calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` against the `Task` returned by `PerformBusyAction` before you call `ContinueWith`

Comment: @KentBoogaart It looks like `ConfigureAwait()` is .NET 4.5. My project is .NET 4.0.

Comment: @HansPassant I posted the call stack in my question.

Comment: @svick I could probably produce a small, complete sample, but I would need to set up a WPF app using MVVM and I'm weighing that effort against just not using `ContinueWith()`.

Comment: @KentBoogaart Using `ConfigureAwait()` doesn't make much sense, there is no `await` here. And if you meant something like `task.ConfigureAwait(false).ContinueWith(…)`, that won't even compile.

Comment: @svick I can't reproduce this in a new project. It must be something specific to the project I have, or the framework we're using.

Comment: @BobHorn Which is exactly why I asked. If we can't reproduce it, I'm afraid we won't be able to help you. And if you can reproduce it, you might find the cause yourself.

Comment: @BobHorn, have you tried `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` or `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` with `ContinueWith`, just for the sake of trying?

Comment: @Noseratio I just tried both and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing IsBusy and BusyMessage by using the dispatcher.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
    {
        this.IsBusy = false;
        this.BusyMessage = String.Empty;
    }));
```