# execute multi-line cmd command in c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am creating java compiler in c# .it is working perfect if there is no input.but it ask forstrong text input it give me error (Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found)

```
public void executeit()
{
 adresss = "";
 string dir = textBox1.Text;
 adresss = dir;
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
 info.CreateNoWindow = true;
 string[] s = new string[30];
 s = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Program Files\Java\", "jdk1*");
 info.WorkingDirectory = s[0] + @"\bin\";
 info.Arguments = "/c javac " + "\"" + dir + "\"";
 Process p = new Process();
 info.UseShellExecute = false;
 info.RedirectStandardError = true;
 info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 label1.Text = "";

 p.StartInfo = info;
 p.Start();

 StreamReader sw = p.StandardError;
 string err = sw.ReadToEnd();

 label1.Text = err;
 if (label1.Text == "")
 {
  label1.Text = "Compiled without Errors";
 }

}
```

and it is java file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class inputtry {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        //get user input for a
        String a=reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("number is:");
         System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling javac through cmd instead of running it alone?

Comment: it executes .class file..how can I run it alone

Comment: Run it alone as in: new ProcessStartInfo("path\\javac.exe");

Comment: will it work for input ?

Comment: I see no reason why it should not work, as it stands now, you are just calling program that will call targeted one, thus creating unnecessary element in chain. Another thing is that you might need to handle StandardInput from your code.

Comment: thanks @PTwr ..i did it like this 

            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
            textBox2.Text = "";
            StreamReader sw = p.StandardError;
            StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
            StreamWriter stwr = p.StandardInput;
            string err = sw.ReadToEnd();
but now deadlock occur ..

Comment: Check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why).