# Process.ErrorDataReceived fired after Process is disposed?

Tags: c#, process, dispose

I have my code below and sometimes get `ObjectDisposedException` at `errorWaitHandle.Set();`.

How could this happen when my process instance is disposed?

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed

```
public static int Execute(string filename, string arguments, out string output, out string error, int timeoutInMilliSeconds = Timeout.Infinite)
    {
        using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false), errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            // separate using for process to ensure this is disposed before handles above.
            using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                StringBuilder outputSB = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder errorSB = new StringBuilder();

                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        outputWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outputSB.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data == null)
                    {
                        errorWaitHandle.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorSB.AppendLine(e.Data);
                    }
                };

                process.Start();

                // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why
                // for why we need to read output and error asynch
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                if (!process.WaitForExit(timeoutInMilliSeconds) ||
                    !outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutInMilliSeconds) ||
                    !errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutInMilliSeconds))
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException(
                        string.Format("Executing [{0}] with argument [{1}] didn't finish within timeout {2} milliseconds", filename, arguments, timeoutInMilliSeconds));
                }

                output = outputSB.ToString();
                error = errorSB.ToString();

                return process.ExitCode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hm.. i don't think i understand your question. If you look at the method, it doesn't accept any resetevent/waithandles as parameters and AutoResetEvent is created within the method. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Apologies - scanned question too quickly - ignor.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the `Process` events can fire in unexpected orders because of their asynchronous nature (i.e. "Exited" being fired BEFORE "ErrorDataReceived").

You also don't know how those events are being wired up under the covers of the Process class so the various object(s) lifetimes are not really known to you. By the time your handler gets called, the Process object could have been (and apparently is) disposed.

I tried to approach this problem almost identically as you; by using `AutoResetEvent`'s and building up the Error / Data strings from within their respective event handlers.

The way I ended up fixing this is by calling `Process.WaitForExit()` twice:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process()

// Process setup code
if(process.WaitForExit(timeout)){

    process.WaitForExit(); // Note the lack of a timeout parameter

    // By now all your events should have fired and your strings built
    string errorString = errorSB.ToString();
}
```

The excerpt from MSDN states:

> When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event
> handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have
> completed when this method returns. To ensure that asynchronous event
> handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that
> takes no parameter after receiving a true from this overload. To help
> ensure that the Exited event is handled correctly in Windows Forms
> applications, set the SynchronizingObject property.
>
> Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56(v=vs.110)

Comment: Didn't work for me, @Boris Modylevsky solution below did work for me.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to subscribe to `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` events to actual methods instead of anonymous methods. This way you can unsubscribe in `Dispose()` method.

See full code here:

https://github.com/borismod/OsTestFramework/blob/master/OsTestFramework/ProcessExecutor.cs