# How to run console application from Windows Service and how to pass argument to it using thread.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, windows-services

I want to run a console application from windows service using threading and want to pass a string as a argument.

> > > Thread t =new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadFunction()));  t.Start();
> > >
> > > ThreadFunction()  {       Process p.StartInfo = new
> > >       ProcessStartInfo("Prog.exe");  p.Start();  }

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to interact with the service or just watch it through its cycle. 

Have you tried anything yourself? I know this is possible as I have or did have some code that will show you how to do it. I just need to dig it out

Comment: i tried like this Thread t =new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadFunction()));    t.Start();     ThreadFunction(){ objProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Prog.exe");
            objProcess.Start();  }

Comment: please edit your question and show more of your code

Comment: `Thread` is for fire-and-forget threads where you are not expecting any response. If you want to get a response from a console app; even to see if the process got an error, you should use [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593).