# Process.WaitForExit hangs - but I only redirect standard input?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm trying to execute a batch script which contains a pause statement at the end which I want to confirm:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(path, arguments);
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.WorkingDirectory = workDir;

var p = Process.Start(psi);
p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
p.WaitForExit();
```

However, this code hangs forever in `WaitForExit` although the process has already finished. I know that you have to read the buffer when redirecting standard output / error. Is there something special about redirecting standard input as well?

Comment: Try to [read input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/139604/1997232)?

Comment: Did you close the `StandardInput` stream?

Comment: You should have the opposite problem, since `StandardInput.WriteLine()` *confirms* more than one *pause* at the time. Unless you set `AutoFlush= false`. Is there just a `pause` in that batch file or something else? Is it a batch (.bat, .cmd) or a different type of *script*? With these settings, you should see the process output in VS Output window...

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Yep, I forgot to close StandardInput! Thanks, resolved. You can formulate your comment as an answer, then I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer to [`RedirectStandardInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=netcore-3.1) documentation and example. You should close the `StandardInput` stream after writing a line to it to properly handle a pause statement

```cs
p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
p.StandardInput.Close();
p.WaitForExit();
```