# Read standard output without leaking memory

Tags: c#, process, shellexecute

How to read standard output without leaking memory? The `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` is a wrong choice on large output because it allocates a large number of chars in SOH.

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
**string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();**
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: [ProcessStartInfo hanging on "WaitForExit"? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why) might help. you may try with  `string output = await p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Process.StandardOutput is a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-7.0), and you can read the content line by line to save memory:

```cs
// Keep looping lines while stream has not ended
while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    // Read a single line
    var line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

    // ... Do something with the line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture output by using `process.OutputDataReceived` event handler and let the process notify your application of output to be received. It even works for the processes that prompt the user to input:

```
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        // Prepend line numbers to each line of the output.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            lineCount++;
            output.Append("\n[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
        }
    });

    process.Start();

    // Asynchronously read the standard output of the spawned process.
    // This raises OutputDataReceived events for each line of output.
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

For more info see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-7.0)